# Java Tapestry: Clearing a count value after a t:if test

Tags: java, html, tapestry

I am printing the first 12 elements of a Comments array. After 12 have been printed, a "More" link is printed. I am doing this using a COMMENT_COUNT int, and iterating it on each comment printed. I want to return the value of COMMENT_COUNT to 0 after the "More" link is printed.

I have left my current hack in place, in which I just call ${clearCount()} after printing the "More" link. What now happens is that 12 comments are printed, then a "MORE" link is printed, and then the boolean value "true" is printed.

I am guessing there is a much, much better way to do this. I am looking for a better way to call ${clearCount()}, or a better way to set COMMENT_COUNT to 0 after printing the "More" link.

--- EDITED TO ADD ----

An additional requirement is that the COMMENT_COUNT counts only the first 12 visible comments (comments may be visible or not depending on the user), so have some ugly nested if statements:

.tml:

```
<t:loop source="currentCategoryTextmedium.commentArraySorted" value="currentComment">
 //test if the current comment should be visible
 <t:if test="isCurrentCommentVisible()">         
    <t:if test="isCommentLessThan12()">
    //print first 12 visible comments
        <span>
            <a blah blah>${currentComment.blahblah}</a>
        </span>
    </t:if>     
  </t:if>                                                           
</t:loop>

<t:if test="isCommentMoreThan12()">
    //print one More link
    <span>
        <a "blah blah">MORE</a>
    </span>
</t:if>

//Clear the COMMENT_COUNT so that the right number of comments print on another element
${clearCount()}
```

java:

```
public int COMMENT_COUNT; 

public boolean isCommentLessThan12() {
    if (COMMENT_COUNT < 12) {
        COMMENT_COUNT++;
        return true;
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
}
public boolean isCommentMoreThan12() {
    COMMENT_COUNT++;
    if (COMMENT_COUNT > 12) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
}

public boolean clearCount() {
    COMMENT_COUNT= 0;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please do not put a lot of logic into UI code,
@uklance is right on that, it's damn ugly!

Answer (score 3):

That's some pretty damn ugly code!!! Try this:

TML

```
<t:loop source="topComments" value="currentComment">         
    <span>
        <a blah blah>${currentComment.blahblah}</a>
    </span>
</t:if>                                                                 
<t:if test="moreComments">
    <span>
        <a "blah blah">...</a>
    </span>
</t:if>
```

Java

```
@Property
private List<Comment> topComments;

@Property
private boolean moreComments;

@Property(write=false)
private SomeType currentCategoryTextmedium;

// custom setter to initialize
public void setCurrentCategoryTextmedium(SomeType current) {
    topComments = getFirst12(current.getCommentArraySorted());
    moreComments = isMoreThan12(topComments, current.getCommentArraySorted());
    currentCategoryTextmedium = current;
}
```

Comment: No arguments at all on the "ugly". I've updated my code above to show why I didn't start by building a list of the first 12 comments- the count currently iterates only if the comment is visible to the user, which complicates it slightly.